# JavaScript/jQuery hover functions behaves funny - array issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<p id="lorem">
    <span class="red" id="n01">L</span>
    <span class="red" id="n02">o</span>
    <span id="n03">r</span>
    <span id="n04">e</span>
    <span class="blue" id="n05">m</span> 
    <span id="n06">i</span>
    <span class="blue" id="n07">p</span>
    <span class="red" id="n08">s</span>
    <span id="n09">u</span>
    <span class="blue" id="n10">m</span>
</p>

<br />

<div id="bar-red"></div>
<div id="bar-blue"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function legend( elem ) {
    var timer;
    var k;
    var h = $( elem );

    if( elem == ".red" ) {
        k = $("#bar-red");
    }

    if( elem == ".blue" ) {
        k = $("#bar-blue");
    }

    h.hover(function() {
        console.log(h);
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null
        }

        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            k.animate({width: "30px"}, 200);
        }, 300)
    },
    function(){
            k.animate({width: "10px"}, 200);
    });
}


legend(".blue");
legend(".red");
```

​To understand the problem a bit better I have also created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QR76j/).
​
When you hover over a blue letter and let the mouse rest there for a short amount of time, the blue bar expands. Same thing for red letters and the red bar. The problem is, sometimes is lags, the bar stays expanded or won't really expand. Why is it like this?

In my production environment I have about 150 letters and the hover is basically unusable. Or could this be because I add the classes dynamically (not in Fiddle)?

Also, while debugging with Firebug, I noticed something strange. I hover over one element and log h, it shows all elements with the class. That's why I think I maybe have some kind of logic error in this function. Maybe it fires multiple times at once and that's why it lags?

Any held is appreciated!

Comment: did you used timeouts for preventing animation conflicts because of consecutively and rapid mouseovers?

Comment: Yes. The mouse has to rest on one point for a short amount of time before the bar expands.

Comment: i updated my answer, check it out again please.

Comment: if you check my answer, i find the stop() first, 25 min ago ;) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11538065/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use timer to prevent mouse over animate conflicts, [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method will be just fine. Also you can try stop(true,false) / stop(false,true) to find your problem's best solution.

If you insist with using timer, check my answer's edit versions. Last one i did it with timer.

[Here is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QR76j/9/)

```
h.bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
     k.stop().animate({width: "30px"}, 200);
  },
  mouseleave:    function(){
     k.stop().animate({width: "10px"}, 200);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the funny behavior is gone now! Do you know any particular reason why `bind` is better than `hover`? I thought `hover` was made for stuff like this.

Comment: yes, bind is well-organized and much more expendable. You can use most f events/trigger methods with bind like 'dblclick', 'submit', 'myCustomEvent', 'mouseenter mouseleave'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
 function legend( elem ) {
    var timer;
    var k;
    var h = $( elem );

    if( elem == ".red" ) {
        k = $("#bar-red");
    }

    if( elem == ".blue" ) {
        k = $("#bar-blue");
    }

    h.hover(function() {
        /*console.log(h);
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null
        }*/
        k.stop().animate({width: "30px"}, 200);
       /* timer = setTimeout(function(){
            k.animate({width: "30px"}, 200);
        }, 300)*/
    },
    function(){
            k.stop().animate({width: "10px"}, 200);
    });
}


legend(".blue");
legend(".red");
```

Comment: You actually commented out the code that makes the effect occur with a slight delay (the mouse has to rest a bit on one spot before the effect starts).